# Python string formatting when string contains "%s" without escaping

Tags: python, string-formatting

When formatting a string, my string may contain a modulo `"%"` that I do not wish to have converted.  I can escape the string and change each `"%"` to `"%%"` as a workaround.

e.g.,

```
'Day old bread, 50%% sale %s' % 'today!'
```

output:

```
'Day old bread, 50% sale today'
```

But are there any alternatives to escaping?  I was hoping that using a dict would make it so Python would ignore any non-keyword conversions.
e.g.,

```
'Day old bread, 50% sale %(when)s' % {'when': 'today'}
```

but Python still sees the first modulo `%` and gives a:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: escaping % is not a workaround, it's a documented and official way of doing this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could (and should) use the [new string `.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) (if you have Python 2.6 or higher) instead:

```
"Day old bread, 50% sale {0}".format("today")
```

[The manual can be found here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings).

The docs also say that the old `%` formatting will eventually be removed from the language, although that will surely take some time. The new formatting methods are way more powerful, so that's a Good Thing.

Comment: Unless you want to print "{{0}} = {0}".format("today"), then you won't like doubling up the curly braces. :^)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ugg, I specifically came here hoping to find a solution to the "{{0}}".format(...) problem...

Answer (score 2):

Not really - escaping your % signs is the price you pay for using string formatting. You could use string concatenation instead: `'Day old bread, 50% sale ' + whichday` if that helps...

Comment: For where I need to support Python 2.5 or prior, this is the method I'll use.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping a '%' as '%%' is not a workaround. If you use String formatting that is the way to represent a '%' sign. If you don't want that, you can always do something like:

```
print "Day old bread, 50% sale " + "today"
```

e.g. not using formatting.

Please note that when using string concatenation, be sure that the variable is a string (and not e.g. None) or use `str(varName)`. Otherwise you get something like 'Can't concatenate str and NoneType'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to replace % by %% where % is not followed by (

```
def format_with_dict(str, dictionary):
    str = re.sub(r"%([^\(])", r"%%\1", str)
    str = re.sub(r"%$", r"%%", str)  # There was a % at the end?
    return str % dictionary
```

This way:

```
print format_with_dict('Day old bread, 50% sale %(when)s', {'when': 'today'})
```

Will output:

> Day old bread, 50% sale today

This method is useful to avoid "not enough arguments for format string" errors.

Comment: There is a problem with replacing only one % occurrence and not replacing two and more % occurrences.