# ValueError: unsupported format character while forming strings

Tags: python

This works:

```
print "Hello World%s" %"!"
```

But this doesn't

```
print "Hello%20World%s" %"!"
```

the error is `ValueError: unsupported format character 'W' (0x57) at index 8`

I am using Python 2.7.

Why would I do this? Well `%20` is used in place of spaces in urls, and if use it, I can't form strings with the printf formats. But why does Python do this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could escape the % in %20 like so:

```
print "Hello%%20World%s" %"!"
```

or you could try using the string formatting routines instead, like:

```
print "Hello%20World{0}".format("!")
```

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 17):

You could escape the % with another % so `%%20`

This is a similar relevant question [Python string formatting when string contains "%s" without escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847272/python-string-formatting-when-string-contains-s-without-escaping)

Answer (score 8):

You might have a typo.. In my case I was saying %w where I meant to say %s.

Answer (score 8):

I was using python interpolation and forgot the ending `s` character:

```
a = dict(foo='bar')
print("What comes after foo? %(foo)" % a) # Should be %(foo)s
```

Watch those typos.

Answer (score 4):

Well, why do you have `%20` url-quoting escapes in a formatting string in first place? Ideally you'd do the interpolation formatting first:

```
formatting_template = 'Hello World%s'
text = '!'
full_string = formatting_template % text
```

Then you url quote it afterwards:

```
result = urllib.quote(full_string)
```

That is better because it would quote all url-quotable things in your string, including stuff that is in the `text` part.

Comment: Python 3.x: import urllib.parse urllib.parse.quote()

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone checking this using python 3:**

If you want to print the following output `"100% correct"`:

**python 3.8:** `print("100% correct")`
**python 3.7 and less:** `print("100%% correct")`

---

**A neat programming workaround for compatibility across diff versions of python is shown below:**

> ***Note**: If you have to use this, you're probably experiencing many other errors... I'd encourage you to upgrade / downgrade python in relevant machines so that they are all compatible.*
> *DevOps is a notable exception to the above -- implementing the following code would indeed be appropriate for specific DevOps / Debugging scenarios.*

```
import sys

if version_info.major==3:
    if version_info.minor>=8:
        my_string = "100% correct"
    else:
        my_string = "100%% correct"

# Finally
print(my_string)
```