# unsupported format character?

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

I have the following code

```
import urllib.request

niveau_zoom_satellite = 0.0001389


def Image(coordinates, image_size, name):


    d1 = "http://eumetview.eumetsat.int/geoserv/wms?LAYERS=overlay%3Ane_10m_coastline%2Coverlay%3Ane_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&VERSION=1.3.0&TILED=true&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=47.640001058578,3.520001411438,48.880001068115,4.7600014209747&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256" % \
               (niveau_zoom_satellite,
                coordinates[0],
                coordinates[1],
                image_size[0] / 2,
                image_size[1] / 2,
                image_size[0],
                image_size[1])
    for line in urllib.request.urlopen(d1):
        if line.startswith("<td align=left><input type=image src="):
            d2 = "http://http://eumetview.eumetsat.int/%s" % (line.split("\"")[1],)
            break
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(d2, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Image((4.37337, 47.43572), (256, 256), "test.jpg")
```

and the problem is

> ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 58

Comment: What line raises the error?

Comment: What line? I suspect you need to escape the `%` in the string as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856523/valueerror-unsupported-format-character-while-forming-strings

Comment: the error in the line 7 (image_size[1])            ((((File "C:/Users/RIDHA/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/33.py", line 26, in <module>
    Image((4.37337, 47.43572), (256, 256), "test.jpg")
  File "C:/Users/RIDHA/.PyCharmCE2017.1/config/scratches/33.py", line 17, in Image
    image_size[1])))

Answer (score 0):

You use a URL as a format string for `%` operator. However, the URL contains several characters that are encoded as `%xx`, where xx is a hexadecimal code of the character (3A for colon `:` and 2F for slash `/`). Those `%` characters are interpreted as beginnings of format specifications. You should either escape them by replacing single `%` with double `%%` to avoid interpretation by `%` operator, or get rid of the `%` operator altogether and use `format` method instead.

BTW, I don't see any *actual* format specifications in your string - what do you really want as value of `d1`?

**Edit:** so I'd guess the correct code is something like this:

```
d1 = "http://eumetview.eumetsat.int/geoserv/wms?LAYERS=overlay%3Ane_10m_coastline%2Coverlay%3Ane_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&VERSION=1.3.0&TILED=true&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX={},{},{},{}&WIDTH={}&HEIGHT={}".format(
    coordinates[0],
    coordinates[1],
    image_size[0] / 2,
    image_size[1] / 2,
    image_size[0],
    image_size[1])
```

I still don't know where niveau_zoom_satellite fits into this.

Comment: i just wont to download an satellite imagery

Comment: Well, this answer didn't really make things clearer. You have an URL, and you have some variables - `niveau_zoom_satellite`, `coordinates`, `image_size` - whose values presumably should replace some parts of your URL. **Which** parts? I would assume that `image_size` contains values that should go after `WIDTH=` and `HEIGHT=` respectively, but what about the rest?

Comment: well, each one of this variables has a number value, for image_size yes they countains values that should go after WIDTH= and HEIGHT= respectively, but the values before that are the coordonate of image

Comment: thak uu sir your really helpped me to find a solution by your questions ..thank uu very mutch

Comment: can uu give me your e-mail please ?

Answer (score 0):

Its complaining about `%3An` in the d1 definition. Better to use str.format() here.

for example:

```
d1 = "www.blabla.com/{var1}asdasd".format(var1=5)
```

which will generate:

```
d1 = "www.blabla.com/5asdasd"
```